# JSPM ... run node app from command line, not via index.html?

Tags: javascript

I often like to play with snippets of javascript code on the command line, rather than inside a web browser.

Is there a way with JSPM to run from the command line?  Does SystemJS care about where it is being ran?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way with JSPM to run from the command line?

yes.

```
npm install -g jspm
jspm run <file>
```

> Does SystemJS care about where it is being ran?

I'm not quite sure what you mean. When using SystemJS with node.js, we are usually requiring the SystemJS module from within the JS code, and it does not rely on the path in the filesystem.

```
var System = require('systemjs');
System.import('foo').then(...);
```